Audio format identification
I have two files that I don't know how to open.  Neither has an extension.
exiftool says both are MP3
filename isn't helpful because they came from an iPhone
eyeD3 says 0445…b24542 is "MPEG2, Layer II [ 160 kb/s @ 8000 Hz - Stereo ]"
and it says 5e43…94ae is "MPEG1, Layer I    [ 192 kb/s @ 32000 Hz - Dual channel stereo ]"
file says 0445…b24542 "contains: - ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio"
and it says 5e43…94ae "contains:CoreAudio Format audio file version 1"
if I add .m4a or .mp3, either way, Amadeus Pro can't read them.
Quicktime Player can't open them.
What other ways are there to handle these two files?

Can you upload these files (or just the first 512 bytes may be enough)?

Aren't music files downloaded to your iPhone are "encryption protected"?

The whole reason for this nuisance is that someone at Apple got the silly idea that we no longer want Finder to have access to recorded audio on the phone..

This seems like an issue with Amadeus in a matter of speaking. You may need to find a program that can successfully read it and transcode them into a stable format, MP3, MP4, or even WAV.
ffprobe, part of ffmpeg can print slightly more details and may provide some additional information (ffprobe [filename]), although eyeD3 seems to have been comprehensive enough. ffmpeg should also be able to extract the audio stream (ffmpeg [input commands] -acodec copy […]) and/or convert it into something more suitable for Amadeus.
0445… is possibly a video file (Wikipedia: MPEG-2 article, presumably with an audio stream too, the container and/or video data itself may explain why Amadeus can't open it. Its audio data is pretty poor, common audio files are at least 44.1kHz, if not 48k or higher.
5e43… is apparently an MP1 file, which I have never encountered in the wild. Wikipedia's MPEG-1 Audio Layer I article is utterly foreign to me.

You should actully use ffprobe instead of ffmpeg.

Do you know what VLC uses under the hood? It’s pretty savvy when I tried it a decade ago ROFL

ffprobe showed 0445… to be a VoiceMemo.  Since 40+ other files were VoiceMemos and could play OK, perhaps it somehow got corrupted.  I copied it again from the same iPhone backup and the new copy played normally.  I'll have to look some more at the other file after I get back from an errand.

And 5e43… turns out to be a .caf file also somehow corrupted.  A fresh copy, renamed to 5e43…94ae.caf opens in Amadeus and is a recording of a baby crying.  It's not a VoiceMemo, and I don't know where it comes from, but ffprobe seems to be the answer.

I truly never remember that ffprobe exists.
